# spring-integration-aws java configuration

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-integration

I want to use spring-integration-aws to upload and read files from amazon s3 in my spring application (full java configured).

This example do exactly what I want to do : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/samples/aws-s3

But it use xml configuration which I can't translate in java configuration.

Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 1):

See [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/dsl/si4demo). It shows progression from XML through java config to DSL (recently presented at SpringOne).

It also has an example of wiring a twitter outbound gateway using Java Configuration, shown in a webinar earlier this year; the same technique can be used for any endpoint, including AWS.

Consider  posting your solution here, or issue a PR against the extension, to assist the community.